# How can I fetch the IP address of two different nodes having same URL

Tags: java, ip

We are having one server (e.g: https://abc.example.com) which has 2 different nodes (having 2 different IPs) just to balance the load for a requests. I want to fetch the IP address of these 2 nodes, so how can I fetch that?

When I am trying to fetch the IP of the server by passing the URL using InetAddress Java API (refer below code) it is giving me the public IP address, but I want to fetch the IP of the 2 different nodes which are there for load balancing.

```
InetAddress ip = InetAddress.getByName(new URL("https://abc.example.com").getHost());
```

So can anyone please help me to achieve this?

Comment: `InetAddress.getByName("abc.example.com")` would be somewhat simpler.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`InetAddress.getAllByName(String host)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getAllByName(java.lang.String)) to get array of all IPs for the given host name.

*From JavaDoc*

> Given the name of a host, returns an array of its IP addresses, based on the configured name service on the system.
>
> The host name can either be a machine name, such as "java.sun.com", or a textual representation of its IP address. If a literal IP address is supplied, only the validity of the address format is checked.
>
> For host specified in literal IPv6 address, either the form defined in RFC 2732 or the literal IPv6 address format defined in RFC 2373 is accepted. A literal IPv6 address may also be qualified by appending a scoped zone identifier or scope_id. The syntax and usage of scope_ids is described here.
>
> If the host is null then an InetAddress representing an address of the loopback interface is returned. See RFC 3330 section 2 and RFC 2373 section 2.5.3.
>
> If there is a security manager and host is not null and `host.length()` is not equal to zero, the security manager's checkConnect method is called with the hostname and -1 as its arguments to see if the operation is allowed.
>
> **Parameters:**
>
> `host` - the name of the host, or null.
>
> **Returns:**
>
> an array of all the IP addresses for a given host name.
>
> **Throws:**
>
> `UnknownHostException` - if no IP address for the host could be found, or if a scope_id was specified for a global IPv6 address.
>
> `SecurityException` - if a security manager exists and its checkConnect method doesn't allow the operation.

Comment: Thanks for your response and help. I have tried this way but getting only one public IP whereas there are 2 nodes with 2 different IPs.

Comment: Was it the reason because we are getting redirected via proxy server, if we bypass proxy then I think I can get the IPs.